How to unit test random geometric functions?
Consider these two functions that return random points in geometric shapes:
// Note: random() returns number in range [0, 1)

function randomPointInRectangle(x, y, width, height, out=new Vector2()) {
    out.x = x + random() * width;
    out.y = y + random() * height;
    return out;
}

function randomPointInCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, out=new Vector2()) {
    radius = sqrt(random() * radius * radius);
    const angle = random() * PI * 2;
    out.x = centerX + radius * cos(angle);
    out.y = centerY + radius * sin(angle);
    return out;
}

I have more such functions, e.g. random points on line segments, in triangles, ellipses, spirals, etc.
How one would approach unit testing these functions, including respecting shape's bounds? Preferably a test would treat these functions as black boxes, so it will not assume how many times random() is called or even what the internal formula is.

Have you considered making the random() function a dependency that you can mock/control during tests? I am going to assume that random() returns a value in the range of 0..1, if you could control the result, you could say "what if it returns 0 every time", or "1 every time", and then test what the results are. However... You're likely wanting to test with different values throughout your method, to ensure different angles vs. different radius doesn't make a difference, and in this situation you probably can't tread the functions as black boxes.

Yes, in my current tests I mock the random() function to return specific values, but this approach means that the tests need to know how many times random() will be called inside tested functions, so in other words the tests assume how the tested function works internally, which doesn't looks good to me.

If you can say "just return 0 every time", you don't need to know how many times it is called, but you also cannot say "return 0 for the radius but 1 for the angle". I am not entirely certain you can guarantee that these functions works as expected in this regard without writing the test with at least some knowledge of the internals. You could, of course, just run the functions a billion times in a test, but this is not a good idea either.

First you need a specification for what the routines do. Then you can start thinking about which properties in the specification you wish to test. The way you select radius suggests you want a uniform distribution per unit of area in the circle. So, do you want to test that the routines conform to that distribution? Are the routines required never to return a point that is, due to floating-point rounding, slightly outside the boundary of the shape? Should they ever return a point exactly on the boundary? randomPointInRectangle will return some points on the low boundaries but not the high.

What about separating the functions into multiple pieces? One that is pure, in terms of only relying on input parameters, so you would pass in a radius and an angle, and then you can test that to your hearts content, and then you also expose the actual function your code should use, that first calls random, and then calls the function you testes? I am pretty sure you won't have to test whether random() returns in the range 0..1.

It looks likely this code uses floating-point arithmetic, so random probably potentially returns 2^53 values. That makes it effectively impossible to test boundary conformance by random testing—There is only one chance in 2^53 that random will hit its low value and one chance in 2^53 it will it its high value. Random testing might be useful for statistically testing the distribution property. Besides that, what mock testing can give is testing whether an implementation conforms to its design…

@EricPostpischil Yes to almost all your questions, I would like to test almost all these aspects you've mentioned, including asymmetry in the rectangle function, as it's intended, excluding maybe the distribution.

… In other words, because ensuring boundary conformance requires numerical analysis of the algorithm (because random testing is insufficient), you have to plan a design for the routine, something that says when random is x or y, that a certain point will be selected using a particular set of numerical operations. Then mock testing can test that design. For that purposes, it can inject random but known (or non-random) values into random and test whether the routines supply the expected results.

(Note that, as long as we are overriding random, then, for the rectangle, which can inject its maximum value and get some assurance the boundary is respected for a particular x and y. But, for the circle, we can inject the maximum value for the radius, but it would not be immediately apparent which values for the angle could cause the routine to exceed the circle’s boundaries. Hence having control of random is still insufficient by itself to probe boundary issues.)

By the way, randomPointInRectangle will exceed its boundary requirements. For some values of x and width, floating-point arithmetic will round up and produce a point on the high border (which you indicate is intended to be excluded) or even beyond it. The circle routine can violate its boundary in all directions.

@EricPostpischil I'm aware of that rounding, but lack knowledge what can be done about it, so I just left the code simple. I guess probability of landing on the high boundary would be similar to random()  returning exactly 0, which would be 1 in 2^53?

@LasseV.Karlsen Separating functions seems interesting, I will try that.

Re “I guess probability of landing on the high boundary would be similar to random() returning exactly 0, which would be 1 in 2^53?”: No, it is affected by the ratio of size to position. Using six-digit decimal floating-point as an example, if x is 10 and width w is .999999, then any random that gives w•random .99995 or greater will cause rounding beyond the boundary (10 + .99995 = 10.99995 ➝ 11). But if x is 10,000, any random that gives w•random .95 or greater will cause rounding beyond the boundary (10,000 + .95 = 10,000.95 ➝ 10,001).
